# Can one send be broken up into multiple recvs?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm learning about C socket programming and I came across this piece of code in a online tutorial

Server.c:

```
    //some server code up here
    recv(sock_fd, buf, 2048, 0);
    //some server code below
```

Client.c:

```
    //some client code up here 
    send(cl_sock_fd, buf, 2048, 0);
    //some client code below
```

Will the server receive all 2048 bytes in a single recv call or can the send be be broken up into multiple receive calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TCP is a streaming protocol, with no message boundaries of packets. A single `send` might need multiple `recv` calls, or multiple `send` calls could be combined into a single `recv` call.

You need to call `recv` in a loop until all data have been received.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the data is ultimately typically handled by the operating system which programs the physical network interface to send it across a wire or over the air or however else applicable. And since TCP/IP doesn't define particulars like how many packets and of which size should compose your data, the operating system is free to decide as much, which results in your 2048 bytes of data possibly being sent in fragments, over a period of time.

Practically, this means that by calling `send` you may merely be causing your 2048 bytes of data be buffered for sending, much like an e-mail in a queue, except that your 2048 bytes aren't even a single piece of anything to the system that sends it -- it's just 2048 more bytes to chop into packets the network will accept, marked with a destination address and port, among other things. The job of TCP is to only make sure they're the same bytes when they arrive, in same order with relation to each other and other data sent through the connection.

The important thing at the receiving end is that, again, the arriving data is merely queued and there is no information retained as to how it was partitioned when requested sent. Everything that was ever sent through the connection is now either part of a consumable stream or has already been consumed and removed from the stream.

For a TCP connection a fitting analogy would be the connection holding an open water keg, which also has a spout (tap) at the bottom. The sender can pour water into the keg (as much as it can contain, anyway) and the receiver can open the spout to drain the water from the keg into say, a cup (which is an analogy to a buffer in an application that reads from a TCP socket). Both sender and receiver can be doing their thing at the same time, or either may be doing so alone. The sender will have to wait (`send` call will block) if the keg is full, and the receiver will have to wait (`recv` call will block) if the keg is empty.

Another, shorter analogy is that sender and receiver sit each at their own end of a opaque pipe, with the former pushing stuff in one end and the latter removing pushed stuff out of the other end.